# Send particular object of Arraylist from JSP to Servlet on click of button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, arraylist

Here I am sending contact no from this JSP to Servlet. On click of a button, I want to send Contact No associated with that particular button. I don't know how to do it please suggest a way...
  Also, table borders are not displaying I tried increasing width and thickness still it not displaying.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>View Employee</title>
<style>
td
{
 padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
th
{
 padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
</style>
</head>




<body style="background-color:powderblue;">


<%@ include file="MenuBar.jsp" %>



<%@ page import="in.idk.service.ViewEmployee" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import= "in.idk.model.Employee" %>
<table>
<tr>
<th width="119"><label>Employee_Name</label></th>
<th width="168"><label>Employee_Contact_No.</label></th>
<th><label></label></th>
</tr>

<%
                     ViewEmployee viewEmployee = new ViewEmployee();
                     List<Employee> list = viewEmployee.getListOfEmployees();

                             for (Employee e : list) {
                 %>
                 <tr>
                     <td width="119"><%=e.getEmployeeName()%></td>
                     <td width="168"><%=e.getEmployeeContactNo()%></td>

                     <td><form action="GetOneEmployee" method="post">

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></form></td>

                 </tr>
                 <%}%>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, both Migrated Pigeon and jangachary sriramadasu responding to my question. Here the answer of my question.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>View Employee</title>
<style>
td
{
 padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
th
{
 padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<%@ include file="MenuBar.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="in.idk.service.ViewEmployee" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import= "in.idk.model.Employee" %>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th width="119"><label>Employee_Name</label></th>
<th width="168"><label>Employee_Contact_No.</label></th>
<th><label></label></th>
</tr>

<%
                     ViewEmployee viewEmployee = new ViewEmployee();
                     List<Employee> list = viewEmployee.getListOfEmployees();

                             for (Employee e : list) {
                 %>
                 <tr>
                     <td ><%=e.getEmployeeName()%></td>
                     <td ><%=e.getEmployeeContactNo()%></td>

                     <td><a name="view" href="GetOneEmployee?id=<%=e.getId() %>">View</a></td>

                 </tr>
                 <%}%>




</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside form assign employee reference to a input of type hidden and give a name to that attribute

```
<input name="emp" value="<%=e%>" type="hidden">
```

Based on emp id retrieve data from db

In servlet read that parameter from request object reference

And for table border use border attribute in table opening tag

```
<table border="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you hit the "submit" button you are sending a request to the server.

You can access the request parameters with request object as below

```
request.getParameter("parameter name");
```

in your case to access the Customer contact number first assign a name to it,then access it in servlet as mentioned above.